# Dell laptop black screen when start up but restart okay

Tags: windows-7, laptop, dell-inspiron

I have a `Dell` `Inspiron 5547` laptop bought in 2014. I updated it to `Windows 10` later. I am happy for its stability as it has been all right for more than 6 years without any big problems.

In recent one year, sometimes (1 in 10), the screen keeps black after pressing the button to power on. I then long-press the button to force power off, then press the button again to start, and it can enter the normal `Windowns 10` interface without any problem.

But I just worry this is not good for the laptop anyway. Is this something I can fix by myself?

I am not sure this black screen problem is due to the `Dell` or `Windows 10`.

---

To update, after fully update the `Dell` drivers, this morning, this issue happens again.

Yesterday evening, after powering off the laptop, the screen turned black. But I can still hear the fan sound lasting for e.g. 30 seconds, so the laptop took some more time to fully power off.

This morning, I can still hear the `Windows` startup music. But only black screen is shown for more than 10 min. I can also hear the fan sound. So I have to long-press to force power off, then press again, and it is all normal now.

It seems that, the system is already started up, but just does not show the screen.

Comment: In can also be hardware - 6 years is a long time for a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Windows problem in my experience.

Use the Dell Updater app and update all drivers including BIOS and Chipset.  Do a final restart and test.

Now run the Dell Hardware test app and see if there are hardware issues. Check this carefully as the laptop is getting older.

Comment: Thank you! I have run the Dell Updater app, and update all the drivers including the BIOS. Let me see in two weeks if the problem happens again.